# Order of [11] in $\mathbb{Z_{335}^x}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Order of `[11]` in $\mathbb{Z_{335}^x}$.
What I did is:
Since, `GCF(11, 335) = 1`
So, I thought
$11^x \equiv 1  \pmod {335} \Rightarrow 11^{\phi(335)} \equiv 1  \pmod {335}$
$x = \phi(335) = 264$
But when I tried it in Wolfram alpha `x = 66(n)`.

Comment: Your work establishes that the order of $11$ will divide $264$. So you need to figure out the appropriate divisors first. You may want to consider $$11^x \equiv 1 \pmod{335} \iff \begin{align*}11^x & \equiv 1 \pmod{5}\\ 11^x &\equiv 1 \pmod{67}\end{align*}$$

Comment: $\begin{cases}
11^x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
11^x \equiv 1 \pmod {67} \\
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
11^{\phi(5)} \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
11^{\phi(67)} \equiv 1 \pmod {67} \\
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = \phi(5) =4\\
x=\phi(67)=66 \\
\end{cases}$    
Since `4` doesn't satisfy the second expression but `66` does satisfy both, so `66` is the answer, right?

Comment: Note that modulo $5$ we have $11 \equiv 1$ so that offers no constraint on the exponent. So we can now work modulo $67$, and the order will be a factor of $66$.

Comment: See the [Order Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2166133/242)